# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' error after updating to Flutter 2.5.3

Tags: flutter, gradle, upgrade

I have just updated to Flutter 2.5.3 having not updated for some time.

I see no issues with running flutter doctor but on running app get the following error. I have limited experience with updating to new versions and would be grateful for any help. Thank you

On running app:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
 C:\Users\dan.hemingway\AndroidStudioProjects\cgc\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

app\build.gradle is as follows. I understand that there may be multiple issues and can update with any additional code as required. Thanks

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in 
the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "32.0.0-rc1"

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "danhemingwaycgc.cgc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by upgrading gradle version by updating build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

Also required gradle-wrapper properties to be udated with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```